# Finding the longest word from user input

Tags: python

I've been trying to complete this practice in python for highschool. It's very simple but I don't have much knowledge about phyton at the moment.It would be nice if someone helped me.

This is what I have to do:

Make a program that returns the longest word of the n words entered by the user. The program will ask after entering each word if you want "another word? y / n".

TY

this is what I've tried so far but it still not working.

```
while True:
  input("Enter a word: ")
  n = ""
  cont = input("Another one? y/n > ")

  while cont.lower() not in ("y", "n"):
        cont = input("Another one? y/n > ")

  if cont == (n):
    def longestLength(n):
      max1 = len(n[0])
      temp = n[0]
      for i in n:
        if(len(i) > max1):
          max1 = len(i)
          temp = i
          print ("The word with the longest length is:", temp,
          " and length is ", max1)
```

Comment: It will be more helpful if you write what's wrong with your code, instead of crying how hard you've been trying to solve your problem.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first - define function at the beginnning, not inside loop. And you defined function but you have to execute this function

Comment: you have to assign value from `input()` to variable - `word = input("Enter a word: ")`

Comment: use readable names - `continue` instead of `cont`. What is `n`?

Comment: it seems in `n` you have string with words - but you have to split it to create list of words - and later you can use `n[0]` to get first word from list - at this moment `n[0]` get first char from string `n`.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I don't know if I understand task: do you have to first ask for all words and later search the longest, or you have search the longest after every added word?

Comment: @furas `continue` is a reserved word, you cannot use it as a varibale.

Comment: @TDG you are right, I missed this detail :) in this situation I would use name `continue_` with `_` or different name like `another`.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and after trying myself, I came up with a solution that should work.

```
def longestWord(arr): # A bubble sort

    lengthofArray = len(arr)-1

    for i in range(0,lengthofArray):
        for t in range(0,lengthofArray):
            if len(arr[t]) > len(arr[t+1]):
                temp = arr[t+1]
                arr[t+1] = arr[t]
                arr[t] = temp
                   
    
    print(f"\n\nThe longest word in the array is {arr[lengthofArray]}\n\n")
    
repeat = True
arr = []
    
while repeat == True:

    word = input("Enter a word: ").lower()    
    arr.append(word)
    userContinue = input("Would you like to input another word? (Y/N)   ").lower()

    if userContinue == "n":
        repeat = False
    
longestWord(arr)
```

Apologies if this was not the answer for seeking since it is different from the code you have written.

Good luck with your coding practise, hopefully this can impress the teacher!

Comment: Thank You very much, that was exactly what i was looking for. Also thank you for being so polite and understanding my situation.

Comment: @DMorGon No problem! I updated the code as I noticed it wasn't functioning fully as intended. Glad I can help :) PS: If you're happy with the code an accept answer would be appreciated.